# Nginx server 301 Moved permanently

Tags: nginx, wordpress

When I did a curl -v http://site-wordpress.com:81 I received this result:

```
* About to connect() to site-wordpress.com port 81 (#0)
*   Trying ip... connected
* Connected to site-wordpress.com (ip) port 81 (#0)

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.12.6.2 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: site-wordpress.com:81
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.2.4
< Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2012 16:28:19 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Pingback: The URL above/xmlrpc.php
< Location: The URL above
```

Seems like this line in my fastcgi_params is causing grief.

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

If I remove this line , I get HTTP/1.1 200 OK but I get a blank page.

This is my config:

```
server {
       listen 81;
       server_name site-wordpress.com;
       root /var/www/html/site;
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        index index.php;
        if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
       }



    location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;  # port where FastCGI processes were spawned
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                }

    location ~ \.css {
                 add_header Content-Type text/css;
                 }

    location ~ \.js {
                add_header Content-Type application/x-javascript;
                }

}
```

This config works with ip and port 80. But now I need to use a domain name and port 81, which doesn't work. Could someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your fastcgi_params and nginx.conf files?

Comment: user  sysops;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    keepalive_timeout  15;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with your WordPress configuration, not your nginx configuration. If you really mean to run the server on port 81, then you have to modify the URL in your WordPress options.

Comment: oh yes, thanks.  I did that for wordpress configs, via the mysql home and siteurl option_name and the option_value for both is http://site-wordpress.com:81/ but still didn't work. Is there somewhere else I might have  missed ?

Comment: Also I checked in the Admin page in the General settings. For both Wordpress and Site address , they are http://site-wordpress.com:81   I can access the site using http://ipaddress:81 but not using http://site-wordpress.com:81 which gives me "The page isn't redirecting properly" on my firefox browser.